# What is the name of this pattern or technique?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

There are objects which need two other objects as parameters. This parameter objects may change during runtime.

I use another object which holds the references to the parameter objects. These references are always up to date.

All the other objects ask this objects for the current parameters. They don't have to be updated anymore. Only this "reference helper" will be updated.

What is the name of this pattern or technique, or the name of the "reference helper"?

Edit: Here is a Java example:

```
class ReferenceHelper {

    private Parameter parameter;

    public ReferenceHelper(Parameter parameter){setParameter(parameter);}

    public Parameter getParameter(){return parameter;}
    public void setParameter(Paramater parameter){ this.parameter = parameter;}

}
```

P.S. I know its almost a bean, but thats not the point, because it has a special purpose.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you're doing with this class? Is it for some kind of "memory management", are you using java to do this? Is Parameter always of the same interface/class or are you just simplifying things for the example. If you can give us more context, we might be able to help you more.

Comment: I have some Swing Actions which are used at several locations. They need two paremeters to perform their actions. I wanted to have a clean way to update them. They don't have to react immidiatly to parameters changes, so I did not use listeners. Another way would be to fetch them from Swing's ActionMap, cast them into their class and then update them. Look not so clean for me. Now I will read the other answers.

Comment: Thanks to all answerers. Its surely about data binding. I now know where to go with it. The Actions were already just calling the view independend action implementation. Now I will write a CONTROLLER which will even make the invocation view independend. The action will only have to deal with the controller which does not change at all. This topic may be closed.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's just called aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

What you're referring to might be a Observer or in fact a more specific Data binder used for data synchronization (e.g. keeping data displayed on a View in sync with its Model).

Depending on whether your so-called *parameters* is just plain data or some kind of event you might be looking at a [Supervising Controller (Presenter)](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/SupervisingPresenter.html) or an [Event Aggregator](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html).

Comment: I think it is obvious data binding technique.

Comment: His code example edit was not up while I was writing this answer, will edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are asking for the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) (Listener).

Comment: That's the pattern the objects would use if they wanted to react to changes to said parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Injection).

EDIT: I say this because you don't want to hard code the object creation in the object that needs them. Instead you want to just request them when needed. So if you look at DI containers like StructureMap or Unity they hold all the information needed to build a dependency that another object needs.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a [Mediator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern).